# Can't navigate to the same page twice in a Xamarin Forms application with Prism

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, prism

I have a list view on page A, when you select an item you move to page B.
If I press the back button, it goes back to the view A, but now I cannot select the item to navigate to page B anymore... the call is made to the INavigationService.Navigate with the proper page name, but nothing happens.

I have binded the SelectedItem from my view to my view model, and upon selection, I navigate, then set the SelectedItem to null to remove the highlighting.

```
  this.NavigationService.Navigate("ViewName", useModalNavigation: false);
  this.SelectedItem = null;
```

I am using Xamarin.Forms 2.2.0.31, Prism 6.1.0 pre4.

Comment: This is probably related to the SelectedItem not changing and the Navigation logic never firing.  Set a break point and make sure you verify you have identified to problem.  If you never call Navigate again, then the issue is somewhere else.

Comment: I have checked this, the Navigate function is called properly. On my SelectedItem setter, if the value is not null, I call my Navigate function (which is shown in the question). At first, I thought it could have been that the navigation service though it was still on the same page, but the GoBack sets it properly

Comment: I can't duplicate this. Submit an issue on the project site and provide a sample that can repo the issue.

Comment: Thanks, I will create a sample project and let you know the details

Comment: @Frank Were you able to reproduce this outside the context of your app? I'm having a very similar problem, but couldn't reproduce in a separate, new project, to submit.

Comment: I was not able to reproduce this outside the context of my app. I believe it was something around the bootstrapping of my app and the way I was registering the views to the unity container